# Ruby:-Find the occurrences of a character in a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking for the Ruby method that can help me find the occurrences of a character in a file.I am looking for all occurrences, not just the first one.

I am able to read the file with the help of `File.read("filename")`.

I do know how to find the no of occurrence in a particular string but dont know how to implement it when finding the characters in the file.

Please help.

Comment: You mean `particular character` or `all characters`?

Comment: @Pavan A particular character..

Comment: Something like this `if File.read(filename).include?('a') puts 'a'.count` will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `File.read("filename")` is not the most efficient way to do it, but it does not matter unless the file is too big, and if you are using it anyway, then `File.read("filename")` is indeed a string, so do it as you would with other strings.

```
File.read("filename").count(some_character)
```

or

```
File.new("filename").each_char.inject(0){|n, c| n += 1 if c == some_character; n}
```

Comment: puts "File.read("filename")".count('a')... will this work..

What is the other way to find it

Comment: It cannot be answered because your question is not clear. What do you mean by find the characters? What is the output?

Comment: I want to find the occurrence of "a" in the entire file.so am using count